# Does PHP close the file after the file handler is garbage collected?

Tags: php, file-io

If I have a short function that opens a file and reads a line, do I need to close the file? Or will PHP do this automatically when execution exits the function and `$fh` is garbage collected?

```
function first_line($file) {
    $fh = fopen($file);
    $first_line = fgets($fh);
    fclose($fh);
    return $first_line;
}
```

could then be simplified to

```
function first_line($file) {
    return fgets(fopen($file));
}
```

This is of course theoretical right now, as this code *doesn't have any error handling*.

Comment: IMO, it's always good practice to explicitly close file handles when you are finished with the file, and not rely on GC to do it for you.

Comment: Based on my experience with Php, chose the most defensive approach. Close the file. Don't trust php.

Comment: It doesn't really address your question, but you want to include a file mode with fopen that describes your intent with the file (e.g. read-only). I'm worried that if the file is opened with read/write and you don't close the resource when you're done, file locks might hang around for a while (until the object is released)

Comment: @Samuel Good point, PHP actually requires a file mode. Shows that you should always run the code first :)

Comment: Personally, I always find it weird when people describe actions with zero tangible benefits as "good practice."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PHP automatically runs the resource destructor as soon as all references to that resource are dropped.

As PHP has a reference-counting based garbage collection you can be fairly sure that this happens as early as possible, in your case as soon as  `$fh` goes out of scope.

Before PHP 5.4 `fclose` didn't actually do anything if you tried to close a resource that had more than two references assigned to it.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: If I have a pointer left open for any reason, will PHP clear it up?

Consider the following (PHP7 syntax)

    function my_prng(int $bytes = 32)
    {
       static $fp;
       if(!$fp) {
          $fp = fopen( '/dev/urandom', 'r' );
       }
       $out = '';
       $cnt = max(32, intval($cnt) ?? 0);
       $out = fread( $fp, $cnt );
       return $out;
    }

assuming we declare the file_pointer static, rather than passing to the function, will PHP clear the $fp when script execution terminates?

I would be very interested to know

Comment: And this whole time I thought I had to wrap resources in a class with fclose() in its __destruct() method to make sure file descriptors didn't leak!

Comment: @sectus It should be added to the fclose() doc page, IMO.

Comment: @Jesse, just add comment, or edit original answer :^ )

Answer (score 13):

Yes. Resources are released automatically when they go out of scope. To wit:

```
<?php

class DummyStream {

    function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path) {
    echo "open $path<br>";
        return true;
    }

    function stream_close() {
        echo "close<br>";
        return true;
    }
}

stream_wrapper_register("dummy", "DummyStream");

function test() {
    echo "before open<br>";
    fopen("dummy://hello", "rb");
    echo "after open<br>";
}

test();

?>
```

Output:

```
before open
open dummy://hello
close
after open
```

The file handle is released as soon as fopen() returns, as there's nothing here capturing  the handle.

Comment: "released automatically" can mean lots of things. Is just the  memory cleaned up? Or is all teardown code safely executed? Is there a good citation for how php does this and exactly what it does?

Comment: Interesting how `close` comes before `after open`

Comment: That's no surprise with reference counting. Since the return value of fopen isn't stored anywhere, the file object has zero reference as soon as the fopen call returns, so the file object is garbage collected immediately.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but it is good practice to close file pointers as soon as you are finished with them. This way, if you have another application which needs write access to that file, it can run gracefully.

Something to look into is the [Garbage Collection](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) feature present in PHP 5.3 and better.