# Save content to file using AJAX and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file, save

Hi there and thanks a lot in advance. 
I'm messing with the following code for like ages and do not get it working. Actually the whole code should only write a DIV to a certain file on my server and give that file a name. Seems to be easy - but actually not to me as I realized.

Here is my code so far:

**HTML / PHP**:

```
<div id="data2save">
<table width="80%" border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="float:left" >
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-top:1px solid #000;border-left:1px solid #000;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">07:00 - 08:00</td>
    <td bgcolor="#99CC00" value="1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#99CC00" value="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#99CC00" value="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table> 
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="save" id="save">

<?php
 $userid = 10;
 $kalenderwoche = date('W', time());
 sprintf("%02d",$kalenderwoche);
 $jahr = date('Y', time());
?>
```

**AJAX:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$("#save").live("click",function() {

var userid = "<?php echo $userid ?>";
var kalenderwoche = "<?php echo $kalenderwoche ?>";
var jahr = "<?php echo $jahr ?>";

var bufferId =$("#data2save").html();

        $.ajax({
             type : "POST",
             url : "saver2.php",
             data: {user_ID: userid , kw: kalenderwoche , jj : jahr , id : bufferId},
             dataType: "html",
             success: function(data){ 
             alert("ok");  
             }
             });
}); 
</script>
```

and the php file which handles the data to save it to a file and seems to contains the error.

**saver2.php:**

```
<?php

$kalenderwoche = $_POST['kw'];
$userid = $_POST['user_ID'];
$jahr = $_POST['jj'];
$data = $_POST['id'];

if (!file_exists($userid.'/')) {        
mkdir($userid.'/', 0755, true);
}

$copyname =  $userid. '/' .$userid. '_' .$jahr. '_' .$kalenderwoche. '.html';   

$handle = fopen($copyname , 'w+');  

if($handle)
 {

 if(!fwrite($handle, $data ))
 echo "ok";
 }


?>
```

Well, thats all. I hope anybody is sharp-eyed because I do not find the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you close your file first?
also, fwrite returns false in case of error, or the length of the file.
so `!fwrite()` returns false if something ( or 0 ) had been written.

```
<?php

$kalenderwoche = $_POST['kw'];
$userid = $_POST['user_ID'];
$jahr = $_POST['jj'];
$data = $_POST['id'];

if (!file_exists($userid.'/')) {        
mkdir($userid.'/', 0755, true);
}

$copyname =  $userid. '/' .$userid. '_' .$jahr. '_' .$kalenderwoche. '.html';   

$handle = fopen($copyname , 'w+');  

if($handle)
 {

 if(fwrite($handle, $data ))
 echo "ok";
 }

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Also I hope you won't fetch that code to a production server as it's full of security holes.

Comment: flcose won't matter in this case as it'll be garbage collected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143343/does-php-close-the-file-after-the-file-handler-is-garbage-collected

Comment: fclose has no influence I realize. and dont worry, I wont use that code for any sensitive data. it's just for private use. but it'll great if it works :)

Comment: !fwrite returns false if the operation succeeds, I don't get the logic of the " ok" message. so where's your error? Is it you won't get a success message back in $.ajax ?

Comment: actually nothing happens. the code should create a file but didnt. when pressing the "save" button I get the errormessage in chrome console "(anonymous function) in line 38". but line 38 is only $.ajax({    I cannot imagine whats the issue in that line

Comment: Can you log php errors? $.ajax is returning an error because of the php error.

Comment: i probably cannot log error because it's seems to be deactived at my server provider. phpinfo() states "error_log no value"

Comment: is anybody here having and idea?