# yii2: how to response image and let browser show it?

Tags: yii2

the same work can be done by follow code：

```
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
readfile('a.jpg');
```

but now I really confused by Yii2's `\yii\web\Response.`

---

What I confused is like that:

1. create a controller and action to provide picture

   See below

   ```
   class ServerController extends \yii\web\Controller
   {
       public function actionIndex($name)
       {
           // how to response
       }
   }
   ```
2. access `http://example.com/index.php?r=server/index&name=foo.jpg`

thanks for the answer!

Comment: Please explain what is exactly your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it like this. I have added another function just for setting the headers. You can move this function in a helper too:

```
$this->setHttpHeaders('csv', 'filename', 'text/plain');

/**
 * Sets the HTTP headers needed by file download action.
 */
protected function setHttpHeaders($type, $name, $mime, $encoding = 'utf-8')
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    if (strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "MSIE") == false) {
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
    } else {
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Pragma: public");
    }
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1979 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Content-Encoding: {$encoding}");
    header("Content-Type: {$mime}; charset={$encoding}");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$name}.{$type}");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
}
```

I also found how yii2 does it, take a look here (scroll to the bottom) https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/48ec791e4aca792435ef1fdce80ee7f6ef365c5c/framework/captcha/CaptchaAction.php

Answer (score 21):

Finally, I did it by follow codes:

```
$response = Yii::$app->getResponse();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
$response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
if ( !is_resource($response->stream = fopen($imgFullPath, 'r')) ) {
   throw new \yii\web\ServerErrorHttpException('file access failed: permission deny');
}
return $response->send();
```

Comment: I've tried your solution. Seems to work! Shoudn't the resource gets closed somehow?

Comment: I have no idea about closing resource connection. Could you tell me the way if you already found it ?

Comment: Usually, one should call fclose() to release a resource. But I think this is done automatically (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143343/does-php-close-the-file-after-the-file-handler-is-garbage-collected). So your solution seems to be okay, I guess.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  When I was wondering the same question, the fact I was looking for was $response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW.

Answer (score 9):

Yii2 already has built-in function for [sending files](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#sendFile()-detail). This way you do not need to set response format and content type will be detected automatically (you can override it if you wish):

```
function actionDownload()
{
    $imgFullPath = 'picture.jpg';
    return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($imgFullPath);
}
```

..

If the file is only temporary created for current download action you can use `AFTER_SEND` event to delete the file:

```
function actionDownload()
{
    $imgFullPath = 'picture.jpg';
    return Yii::$app->response
        ->sendFile($imgFullPath)
        ->on(\yii\web\Response::EVENT_AFTER_SEND, function($event) {
            unlink($event->data);
        }, $imgFullPath);
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer, use the built-in Yii2 method!

Comment: keep in mind, this does not add header fields for caching.

Answer (score 7):

in yii2 you can return a response object from class [yii\web\Response](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html) in action. so you can return a own response.

for example display image in yii2 :

```
public function actionIndex() {
    \Yii::$app->response->format = yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    \Yii::$app->response->headers->add('content-type','image/png');
    \Yii::$app->response->data = file_get_contents('file.png');
    return \Yii::$app->response;
}
```

[FORMAT_RAW](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#$format-detail): the data will be treated as the response content without any conversion. No extra HTTP header will be added.

Answer (score 3):

The Yii2 way:

```
Yii::$app->response->setDownloadHeaders($filename);
```

Comment: thanks for answer! but it seems you did not follow my question.