# Yii2 access to files only to authorised users

Tags: yii2

I have a "files" folder in Web, where I am saving all the user's  files.

http://localhost/myweb/files/ we can see all the images inside that folder.

So, I have  question:

How to grant access to this folder only for authorised users?
Thanks!

Comment: hum.... why users can see an image folder?

Comment: htacces file , search info about that

Comment: not sure if this has anything to do with `Yii`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to store the images outside of the web accessible folder and serve them with php. For downloadable files you can use [this function](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#sendFile()-detail), but to serve images in the browser I believe you would have to change the headers like in [this non-yii answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851849/output-an-image-in-php) or [this yii-related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799649/yii2-how-to-response-image-and-let-browser-show-it).