# Does PHP have close-less file reading syntax?

Tags: php, python, file-io, coding-style

In Python, there's a good convention that forces file handles to be closed when you're done with them:

```
with open('file', 'r') as myfile:
  ...do stuff with myfile...
...continued code, after closing...
```

"This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks" (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Similarly, Clojure apparently has the [with-open](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-open) construct, so I assume there is a similar construct for Java.

I haven't found the equivalent operation in PHP - what type of block can I use in PHP to similarly not have to handle every `fclose` after every `fopen`?

Comment: it does not explicit answer your question, however it should be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143343/does-php-close-the-file-after-the-file-handler-is-garbage-collected

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you'll have to wrap it in a function.  When the file handle variable goes out of scope, the file is closed.  Just call the function repeatedly for multiple files.

Comment: Example of using generator for file reading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php#112985

Comment: Couldn't the same be said for Python though, that is, don't use `with open`, use a function that does stuff to a file?