# Does php close all open files on exit?

Tags: php

Does php, run via cli or mod_php, close open files on exit?

```
$fd = fopen($fname, "rb");
// ...
exit();
```

So, does php/mod_php automatically close $fd ?

Comment: yes:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/12143588/4248328

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143343/does-php-close-the-file-after-the-file-handler-is-garbage-collected

Comment: Yes it does, but as multiple invokations of your script can be running at the same time you might end up with corrupt data as they both try to write to the same file at the same time, so you'll need to do proper file locking in your code and close the file as soon as you're done with it so other instances can access it safely