# How to prevent socket connection shutdown?

Tags: php, sockets

This is the code that I have:

```
//main.php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 21626;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);
socket_getsockname($socket, $host, $port);
socket_listen($socket, 5);

$clients = [$socket];
while(true)
{
    $read = $clients;
    $write = [];
    $except = [];
    if (socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0.5) < 1){
        continue;
    }
    if (in_array($socket, $read)) {
        handle_request($socket);                       
    }                
}

function handle_request($socket)
{
    $client = socket_accept($socket); 
    $data = socket_read($client, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ); 
    socket_write($client, $data . "\n"); 
}
```

It creates TCP server which runs at port 21626. To actually run it, do this:

```
$ php main.php
```

And to make a request you may need to use telnet like so:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 21626
```

The problem that I face is that every time when I make a request, this request is processed by the server and the client socket immediately shuts down. It looks like so:

[image]

As you can see, I type "Hello", the server responses with echo and closes connection. But I want to keep this connection alive.

So, my question is, why client socket is closed, even if I do not do this explicitely?

Comment: Please follow the advice of [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of linking to a larger code base and expecting others to debug your code. But my guess is that your server simply closes the connection after handling a single request and that's why the client socket is closed automatically too.

Comment: I will try it in a minute.

Comment: Seems like you aren't checking for errors anywahere. My guess your error is you do not specify the content length when writing to socket.

Comment: The server itself keeps running and waits for other connections

Comment: I will post a minimized and completely verifiable example in a second. Please, have a look.

Comment: I did it. Please, have a look. Thanks!

Comment: As I expected: your handler accepts the connection, reads something, writes something and is done - and will implicitly close the socket connection to the client when done which will cause the client to close its side of the connection.

Comment: And why does it implicitely close the socket connection? I do not see in documentation, that after writing to client socket, it shuts down.

Comment: @Jacobian: When you return from `handle_request` the file handle `$client` gets out of scope.  This means it will be garbage collected and closed during this. If it would not be doing this you would leak file handles since the handle is no longer accessible after leaving `handle_request`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143343/does-php-close-the-file-after-the-file-handler-is-garbage-collected